# How do you use geth console commands on an ubuntu server

Tags: go-ethereum, ubuntu

I followed [these instructions](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu#building-from-source) to install a geth node on an ubuntu vps. If I try a [command](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Command-Line-Options) via ssh it says `geth: command not found`. Do I need to be in a specific folder to run the commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've [built from source](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu#building-from-source), which I think your description (and link) implies, then your built binary won't have been automagically copied to the `/usr/bin/` directory. In this case you'll need to run the `geth` command from the location specified in the instructions, which is `/build/bin/geth`.

If you want to be able to run `geth` from anywhere, you'll either need to:

- Add the `/build/bin/` directory to your `$PATH`,
- Manually copy the built `geth` binary to `/usr/bin/` (which is already part of your `$PATH`).

Alternatively you could [install from the PPA](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Installation-Instructions-for-Ubuntu#installing-from-ppa) and have all this done for you automatically. (This is what I would do, unless I wanted the very latest code.)

Comment: I still get the same error if I run it in the go-ethereum directory

Comment: Okay, I hadn't read the wiki properly :-) The very final instruction says you can run it from `build/bin/geth`, which is where the `make` step must put it instead of leaving it in `go-ethereum`.

Comment: build/bin/geth is an executable file. running it starts the node.

Comment: Great, glad it worked :-) (That's what you were after, right?)

Comment: I wanted to use the geth command line options so that I could run as a light client

Comment: Okay, so now that you're able to run `geth` you should be able to make use of the options as well. e.g. `geth --light`, and any other options you want to pass to it.

Comment: I was trying to run geth with options from inside the bin folder where the geth executable file is which gave the error. You can just add options to `build/bin/geth` e.g. `build/bin/geth --light`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61223/discussion-between-richard-horrocks-and-joe).